# Dynamic paint with particles

Tags: particles, dynamic-paint

I have a particle emitter. It emits spheres and an object set as brush... let's call it a "paint ball".

I have a canvas. The original "paint ball" I have created as a brush does exactly what I want, if I move it over the canvas it paints the surface during animation, but non of the generated particles do.

I went as far as making the emitter a brush, hoping the particles emitted, would inherit it's properties, but that did not help either.

I know I am doing something stupid wrong but can't for the love of God figure it out.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

In order to have the particles act as a brush, you need to set the emitter to be a brush. Then change the type to a particle system.

[image: Change Settings]

This tells the dynamic paint to use the particles as the brushes, not the actual object.
The particles will then paint the canvas as expected.

[image: Paint]